# setting personal blockchain Server/Node to store website reviews

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, blockchain-data-storage

###### Hello & Good Day,

> I wanted to setup a bitcoin based web application to store website reviews **[my personal project not for mining coins or providing bitcoin distributed node]**. I just wanted to store the user website reviews like other reviews website does, but I wanted to store the data in a bitcoin server. I know I can create a web application and store user reviews by encrypting it and then decryption the same.
>
> > I don't want to create wallet etc, I'll just store the transaction number with user id who posted the review & then I'll retrieve the same using the user-id and transaction number or may be something similar.

> My project idea is to create a secure and transparent voting systems that leverage blockchain technology to provide secure and transparent voting systems & Blockchain is a decentralized ledger technology that allows for secure & transparent record-keeping.
>
> > So here each vote will be recorded on the blockchain, providing a temper-proof and transparent record of the voting process.

It would be great if anyone can help and/or guide me on how to achieve this using blockchain technology, I'm looking for a good starting point? and looking whether it is possible or not.

Thanks for reading, please help with answers and comments, **Thanks in advance**